# Socket closed exception android

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

I am  using rx java with  Retrofit, okhttp. 
After downloading the content, while reading input sream getting "Socket Closed"

Tried with different ways like:
* getting the response from onNext method, then reading input stream

my Code Looks Like This:

```
mApi.getPdf(mUserManager.getUserProfile().getAuthToken())
            .compose(mRxUtils.applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseBody>() {


                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mApiErrorManager.handleError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody downloadPDFModelResponse) {


                    downloadFile(downloadPDFModelResponse, myFile);

                }
            });
```

Download Function Looks Like This:

```
private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body, File myFile) throws IOException {

    int count;
    byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
    long fileSize = body.contentLength();
    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
    File outputFile = myFile;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    long total = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //int timeCount = 1;
    while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) { //here getting Socket closed exception

        total += count;
        int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize);

        mEventBus.post(new DownloadProgress(progress));

        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    mEventBus.post(new DownloadProgress(DownloadProgress.COMPLETE));
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    bis.close();


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'reading input stream'? What is your input stream? What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you post some code with your logcat?

Comment: May be this will help you:
[your ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8840042)

Comment: I am added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got Answer From This link , How to go to Download using RX-Java and retrofit

[Downloading file using RX-Java and retrofit](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/retrofit-2-and-rxjava-for-file-downloading-in-android/)